# Android Receive UDP broadcast from C# desktop app over LAN?

Tags: c#, android, udp, broadcast, lan

I'm trying to create a sever application on PC for many android devices using the same wi-fi network.
The devices will find the server's IP by receiving UDP broadcast from it contains the server IP data.
I've started by creating a sample udp broadcaster in C# and udp receiver in java but I never managed to get the packet on the android side . here is the code :

C#:

```
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, listenPort);
listener.Connect(groupEP);
listener.EnableBroadcast = true;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
try
{
    while (!done)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("broadcast");

       Thread.Sleep(400);

       listener.Send(data,2);

     }
```

Android code :

```
DatagramSocket socket;
try {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(11000);
    socket.connect(getBroadcastAddress(), 11000);
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
    byte[] buf = new byte[4];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
```

The Internet Permission is set correctly in the manifest. still not able to receive the packets.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Me Me also trying same thing and cant able establish connection, can you post your worked code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Make sure you don't have any firewalls (software or hardware) blocking you
- Consider using Wireshark:

  http://www.wireshark.org/
- Look at this example:

  http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP

Comment: Thanks , by using Wireshark I found that 255.255.255.255 isn't working instead I used my local LAN broadcast address 192.168.XX.255 and the packet is now propagating throw the network . but still I'm not receiving it on the android by the above code

Comment: What do you mean changing address on both ends? To which address? Could you post your working code?