# udp sender under android via USB > ethernet

Tags: android, udp, usb, ethernet

I'm a beginner with Android dev and want to establish an UDP dialog with a PC and my tablet.
the scheme is the following :

Android (server)<--> USB <--> ETHERNET <--> PC (client)

and using a UDP transmission( IPV4 address and port) .

I don't find any examples, if someboby ever have a similar project, pls could you give me some help

Many thanks

Comment: You have to at least have attempted it yourself.  StackOverflow revolves around specific problems and answers.  If you're bored now, that may only get worse with this approach.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sry for this "sentence" but i really need your help. I can't progress in my project since few days. I just think someboby were already have this problem and maybe can help me

Comment: ah when you said bored, do you mean frustrated?  Where is the code you are frustrated with?  You only need to copy the specific piece.  Or if you're looking for how, there is a LOT out there for Android and UDP.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784227/android-receive-udp-broadcast-from-c-sharp-desktop-app-over-lan

Comment: Yeah, i have the UDP code, USB code, but no one for usb -> ethernet.Also i need to know if micro USB > ETHERNET > PC connection is possible .